# Cambiar el formato de fecha en JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo una `query` en que una fecha se inserta en la base de datos el problema es que me la ingresa como `MM/DD/YYYY` y yo quiero que sea `DD/MM/YYYY`
la fecha me la trae así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 Finicio = fields.txtFInicio
```

He probado con `replace` pero no me funciona.

la fecha la saco de miformulario en PUG y uso la libreria daterangepicker pero esta no me permite modificar el formato de la fecha

```
.col-8.p-5.border-right.border-bottom
                            .input-group.date#datetimepicker1
                                input.form-control(type="text", 
 name="txtFInicio", autocomplete="off" required)
                                .input-group-addon
                                    i.fa.fa-calendar
                        .col-4.p-5.border-right.border-bottom F.Termino
                        .col-8.p-5.border-right.border-bottom
                            .input-group.date#datetimepicker2
                                input.form-control(type="text", name="txtFTermino", autocomplete="off" required)
                                .input-group-addon
                                    i.fa.fa-calendar
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de lo que haz hecho, en vez de poner una imagen, es más fácil que la comunidad pueda ayudarte si colocas código.

Comment: Cómo obtienes la fecha? de un `input tipo date`?

Comment: Edite mi pregunta con el codigo donde realizo la extraccion

Comment: Tal vez esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500058/how-to-change-date-format-mm-dd-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-date-picker/37473649) te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada debes poner el código mínimo para replicar tu problema aun así te voy a dar una respuesta general de como se formatean fechas en js partiendo de un string.

```
    //esto es la fecha como la tienes

    var stringDate='04/18/2019 12:00 pm';

    //acá conviertes esa fecha en texto a fecha tipo Date()

    var date=new Date(stringDate);

    //aca usando toLocaleDateString conviertes la fecha tipo Date() a texto 
    //con 
    //la codificacón local de USA que es DD/MM/YYYY

    var usaDate=date.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
```

así como 'es-US', hay mucho otros posibles valores que alteran el resultado.

si quieres mas información sobre toLocaleDateString acá hay un link muy útil.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Muchas Gracias , me sirvio mucho tu ejemplo :)